# ASP.NET MVC Datepicker Formatting display from model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using MVC 5 with `Boostrap.Datepicker` library from NuGet. My current `datetimepicker` is in the format of:

```
format: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm'
```

It works fine for creating records and storing using `dbcontext`, however when it comes to editing records, it displays the data in the wrong format.

Expected output when display:

```
2017/03/30 12:00
```

Wrong output when display:

```
0003-01-10 12:00
```

In my `ViewModel`, I had the property set to the following `DataFormatString` but it still does not work.

```
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0: YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm}")]
    [Display(Name="Exam Date")]
    public DateTime ExamDate { get; set; }
```

How should I set the `DataFormatString`? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change DisplayFormatString to this one:

```
 [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy'/'MM'/'dd hh:mm}")]
```

or:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy\/MM\/dd hh:mm}")]
```

Comment: how do I format the datepicker to have the same formatting?

Comment: Make sure that datepicker is set to custom: DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "yyyy/MM/dd";